# tcl list index in regexp

Tags: regex, list, indexing, tcl

Is there a way to use the list index in a regexp ?

I've tried with this but it doesn't work :

```
if {[regexp {.*\[lindex $mylist 2\].*} $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

the value located at list index 2 of the list named mylist is not replaced in the regexp.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think regex can include variables - everything inside the \\'s is part of the regex.

Comment: Possible if you set your expression using `-all` and `-inline` and then set the list index from that variable pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see if some short simple string is present in another, `regexp` is not the right approach. Instead, use `string first`:

```
if {[string first [lindex $mylist 2] $mystring] >= 0} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

If the list really has a regular expression in its third element, then it's enough to do this because Tcl always detects if an RE matches anywhere (it's patterns are unanchored by default):

```
if {[regexp -- [lindex $mylist 2] $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

The `--` is just in case the RE starts with a `-` character, which can cause confusion. You could also use `regexp` to work a bit like that `string first` recipe:

```
if {[regexp ***=[lindex $mylist 2] $mystring]} {
```

But the code with `string first` will be faster! If you want anything much more complicated than this, it's probably a good idea to *stop* and think whether what you're doing is the right approach; when one finds oneself doing complicated substitutions in regular expressions, one is usually getting into a mess. (Or at least that's when I know *I* need to rethink.) Asking here — while providing a bit more context — can help you figure things out.

Comment: Ah, I tend to forget about the switches causing trouble. Good point! The `***=` is something new to me. I wonder how `regexp` interprets it.

Comment: @Jerry: It interprets everything after a leading `***=` as a literal (unanchored). Documented in re_syntax, but still really obscure…

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've combined several string first to obtain the result that I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using regexp that way. You don't have to match the whole string, you know?

You should be able to use:

```
if {[regexp [lindex $mylist 2] $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

Note that as long as there is a match *anywhere* in the string, regexp will match and return 1.

However, this might give you unexpected results with regexp metacharacters. If `[lindex $mylist 2]` doesn't contain any, you should be good.

Unless the element in the list was intended to be a regexp string, then won't be any issues.

---

If you have metacharacters in the element of the list, you might use another regexp first to escape them:

```
if {[regexp [regsub -all {[\]\[+*.^${}()?\\]} [lindex $mylist 2] {\\\0}] $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

`[regsub -all {[\]\[+*.^${}()?\\]} [lindex $mylist 2] {\\\0}]` adds a backslash to the metacharacters in `[\[\]{}()?+*.^$\\]` (i.e. the following characters `[]+{}()?+*.^$\`)

Comment: If you've not got what you think is an RE in the list, _rethinking the whole approach_ is going to be a wise move!

Comment: @DonalFellows I'm not that all familiar with all the string functions, but are you thinking about something like `string first [lindex $mylist 2] $string`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that The braces inside the regex prevent evaluation of the list command.
There are various ways you can solve this, one of them is to give up the braces, and use quotation marks which allow evaluation of commands. In this case you need to escape the control characters:

```
if {[regexp ".*\\[lindex $mylist 2].*" $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

Alternatively you can use the subst command, but this would be verbose:

```
if {[regexp [subst -nobaclslashes {.*\[lindex $mylist 2\].*}] $mystring]} {
    puts "OK"
}
```

The subst command with the switch I enabled substitutes everything inside it, except for the backslashes.